# Get All keys in Firebase Realtime Database Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Database:

[image: 1]

```
const srchBTN = document.getElementById('search-q');
const database = firebase.database();
const rootRef = database.ref('users/CS');

srchBTN.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
const input = document.getElementById('user-q').value;


  rootRef.on('value', snapshot => {
    
      console.log(snapshot.val());
  
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `snapshot.forEach` which iterates over the child nodes of a snapshot. So:

```
rootRef.on('value', snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(child => {    
    console.log(child.key, child.val());
  });
});
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [listen for value events on lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).